# Case Comments public/private after Spring '12

Tags: customer-portal, servicecloud

So with the release of Spring '12, the [self-service portal is no longer available](https://na6.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/case_comments.htm) for new Salesforce Orgs. Also, it seems that the ability to mark a case comment either public or private is no longer available though the documentation doesn't seem to have been updated to reflect this. I find this strange because even without the self-service portal being available, there is still a need to mark Case Comments as either public or private. We want to implement a customer portal and use this public/private Case Comment functionality to either hide or show case comments. It looks like this is no longer an option and we'll have to create something custom.

Am I understanding this correctly? Are there any workarounds? I have a case opened but they didn't offer much information on what, if anything, could be done.

Answer (score 2):

When I use the standard UI I see a checkbox for Public on Case Comments. Are you referring to adding comments via the Self-Service Portal?

[image]

Comment: Was your org created prior to Spring '12? If so, then you still have the self-service portal and the ability to make Case Comments public or private. Our org was created in Summer '12 so we don't have it.

Comment: Yes, ours has the SSP. I didn't realize that yours did not have it.

Comment: Yes, anything after Spring '12 will not have SSP

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that Salesforce has done away with the portals, they have actually replaced them and not just eliminated the functionality altogether.  Portals have been replaced by Communities.  Here is some information on the Salesforce Communities:

Salesforce Communities Overview
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_overview.htm&language=en_US

Comment: They're not completely comparable; Communities have additional licensing requirements while the old SSP allowed limited access for any Contact that had been activated.